# Excel VBA automatically delete unused rows of table in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am populating an bookmarked table from excel and I''m using the following code to delete rows that haven't been used. The process of deleting row by row is slow, any idea how to edit to delete all unused rows in one go?

```
For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If Sheets("Bookmark Data").Range("B3").Offset(bmRow + lRow - 1, 2) = "" Then 'And lRow <> 1 Then
        .Rows(lRow - delCount).Delete
        Let delCount = delCount + 1
```

Comment: The same way you would manually do this: filter on blank and delete the resultant range via `xlSpecialCellsVisible`. Will be much faster given no loop and you only have one instance of deletion rather many (*one per blank row*)

Comment: What is the object in the With block?  You really need to post more of the code.

Comment: Hi Tim, apologies, it's as follows: 
dim MyTbl As Word.Table
With MyTbl

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Word table has no vertically-merged cells, try:

```
Dim r As Long
With MyTbl
  For r = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Rows(r)
      If Len(.Range.Text) = .Cells.Count * 2 + 2 Then .Delete
    End With
  Next r
End With
```